# Possible for input/useState not to be set on button click?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, use-state

Do I need to worry that `fetchClassesSearchedByName(searchName);` will not have a `searchName` value? Is it possible my button click is faster than `searchName` being set?

```
// On input
const [searchName, setSearchName] = useState('');

// Text input
<input
    type='text'
    value={searchName}
    onChange={(e) => setSearchName(e.target.value)}
/>

// On button click
const searchNameBtn = (e) => {
        fetchClassesSearchedByName(searchName);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to worry that `fetchClassesSearchedByName(searchName);` will
> not have a `searchName` value?

You have defined initial `searchName` state and all the `setSearchName` calls pass valid defined values. And so long as all state updates are valid defined values, there's no chance for `fetchClassesSearchedByName` to be called without a defined `searchName` value.

> Is it possible my button click is faster than searchName being set?

Yes, this is entirely possible, ***BUT*** also entirely unrealistic. It's possible because React state updates are not immediate, but are enqueued and asynchronously processed.

Consider the follow example. There are two inputs with `onChange` handlers.

- **Input and handler #1:** The first input attempts to simulate clicking the button immediately after enqueueing a state update, but due to the way Javascript enclosures and the event loop work, the button's `onClick` event is processed *before* React processes the state update because it's synchronous within the `onChange` handler function's scope. The `fetchClassesSearchedByName` appears to be a "render cycle behind" because it's logging the unupdated state.
- **Input and handler #2:** The second input attempts to simulate clicking the button immediately after enqueueing a state update, but uses a `setTimeout` of 0. This places the click event callback at the end of the event queue. Note that this is the earliest possible the button can even be clicked *after* the state update was enqueued. React's state update is processed, then the click event is processed. Note here that the `fetchClassesSearchedByName` now always sees the updated React state.

```js
const fetchClassesSearchedByName = (value) => console.log(value);

function App() {
  const buttonRef = React.useRef();
  const [searchName, setSearchName] = React.useState("");

  const changeHandler1 = (e) => {
    setSearchName(e.target.value);
    buttonRef.current.click();
  };

  const changeHandler2 = (e) => {
    setSearchName(e.target.value);
    setTimeout(() => {
      buttonRef.current.click();
    }, 0);
  };

  const searchNameBtn = (e) => {
    fetchClassesSearchedByName(searchName);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <label>
          Input 1 w/ synchronous button click
          <input type="text" value={searchName} onChange={changeHandler1} />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Input 2 w/ asynchronous button click
          <input type="text" value={searchName} onChange={changeHandler2} />
        </label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button ref={buttonRef} type="button" onClick={searchNameBtn}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 1):

setState is asynchronous, so it is possible if you've got the reflexes of an old west gunslinger.

Your default value is `''`, though, so I don't think you'll need any error handling as long as `fetchClassesSearchedByName` can take an empty string.